# How do I hide the controls in Highslide Media Viewer?

Tags: javascript, css, highslide

is it possible to hide the controls in the Highslide entirely?

I'm looking for something like

```
hs.showControls = false;
```

but of course any other solution would be fine as well.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Highslide JS configuration, in the hs.addSlideshow section, set **useControls: false**.

Comment: Yes, I have already tried `hs.addSlideshow({useControls: false});` but that only causes the control panel to move to the upper left corner of the screen. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hmmm... Works when I do it - there is no controlbar present. A link to your site would help.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm currently developing in our dev environment on our local server. Appreciate your help. `.highslide-controls {display: none;}` at least works for me. I honestly believe your answer is the proper one

Comment: As always, there are about a half-dozen ways of skinning the cat. You could also set the overlay opacity to 0.0! :)

Comment: Is there a way to attach the argument to the onclick-event: `onclick="return hs.htmlExpand(this,{contentId: 'someId'})"`

Comment: I don't think there's a way to override the settings for the overlay inline.